# laravel ajax return 405

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send data with ajax t controller and i get `405` error

## Code

`JS`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').on('click', '.addbundlebutton', function(e){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            var data= [];
            $("input:checkbox[name=bundleProducts]:checked").each(function(){
                data.push($(this).val());
            });

           // data are like ['41', '46'] in console //

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "{{ url('testadd-bundle') }}",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.success);
                    $(".addbundlebutton").remove();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Error:', data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

`Route`

```
Route::post('/add-bundle', 'frontend\BundleController@add');
```

`Controller`

```
public function add(Request $request){
  //testing data...
  $data = $request->all();
  return response()->json($data);
}
```

`Screenshot`

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

Comment: did try to add _token: token to your data

Comment: The URL is different from URL on web.php

Comment: @sajadHaibat yes you're right thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use this URL: `url: "{{ url('testadd-bundle') }}",`

But your route is set to be:

```
url('/add-bundle')
```

So try that instead. 405 means method not allowed, which means you try post on a get route for example.